# Is there a decent private message plugin for Wordpress?

Tags: plugin-recommendation

I've tried Private Messages for Wordpress, but are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following ones with good or fairly good ratings:

- [WP Private Messages](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-private-messages/)
- [Cartpauj PM](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cartpauj-pm/)

Answer (score -2):

No, there is not. Cartpauj PM is the only one I found that worked properly, but it uses login name instead of display name, so it is severely limited. Additionally, the Cartpauj site has been down for some time.